# How to apply java ExecutorService and Executors class here

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to use thread pool in option 2 to replace code in option 1. How can I achieve that?
1
    1. Using Join

```
Thread e1 = new Thread(new EventThread("e1"));
e1.start();
Thread e2 = new Thread(new EventThread("e2"));
e2.start();

 e1.join();
 e2.join();

 // from here 'main' thread continue
```

2.Using thread pool
Now I want to do the same job using a ExecutorService class

```
public class EventThread implements Runnable{
   public EventThread(String message){
   }
} 

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Runnable worker = new EventThread("");
executor.execute(worker);


executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

// from here 'main' thread continue

Does this do exactly same thing as the first one? Or is my code right?
Thank you.

Comment: P.S. I see you have 26 questions with no accepted answer. Please do accept answers, both for rewarding good answers and to mark your questions as answered. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

No. The only difference in functionality is that in option 2 you only have one thread executing. You still have to add each worker to it, the `Fixed size` is only a maximum amount of threads that can be ran concurrently (if you add a third it will wait until one of the earlier added threads are finished before running it).

Also, the busy waiting (the while loop with condition `!executor.isTerminated()`) is not recommended and bad practice. Instead, I recommend using [`executor.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) or at the very least have a `Thread.sleep()` in the loop.

Comment: What about join()? Can I make sure the main thread won't continue before the 2 threads finish first? Thanks. In the first case, the two 'joins' ensures this.

Comment: Yeah, join() on both threads will do that, just like executor.isTerminated() or executor.awaitTermination() will only be true if and only if they both have finished!

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you'll have 2 threads running but in the second example even though you have a threadpool of 2 threads you are only giving 1 runnable to run. So the second thread in the pool would not be used.

You can also use [awaitTermination()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) after the shutdown instead of the while loop:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
  executor.execute(new EventThread("e"+i));
}
executor.shutdown();
try {
  executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: Doe this make sure the two threads will finish before the "main" thread continues when "finished all threads" is printed? How to join() in this case?